# Displaying Emoji in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, emoji

I have a Google Chrome Extension that supports chat. The chrome extension displays the messages sent to you in desktop notification. I have noticed that whenever I send an emoji from an iPhone, it correctly displays in the Desktop notification. But when I try to display the same emoji in the actual application (it's an iframe injected into the page), it appears as a square.

Seems like there's an open bug at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=62435. 
I was wondering why it works correctly in Desktop Notification and not otherwise? Also, is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Also please notice - list of emojis for country flags.           Emoji flags are supported on most major platforms, except Windows which displays two-letter country codes instead of emoji flag images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just implemented Emoji support in my extension using the open-source [Twemoji library](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji).

In the simplest form, it involves adding a `.js` file and calling a function on a DOM element to replace Unicode emoji with Twitter CDN provided images:

```
twemoji.parse(node);
```

See the repository readme for more options.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome will now support emojis natively (only OSX). You can wait a few weeks until the stable version is released with this feature, or you can download the dev-version form [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?platform=mac&extra=devchannel), that already contains this feature.

Btw, if you want to test if it works, you can use this [page](http://getemoji.com/) (works like a charm).

Comment: I've read in the news that this only applies to OS X. Is that correct? Can you provide a source for your information?

Comment: You are right, I didn't clarify that was on OSX 10.10 (Yosemite). Which OS are you using? Have you tried downloading the dev-channel?

Comment: No I haven't, but I refer to [this article](http://thenextweb.com/google/2015/01/11/emoji-support-finally-coming-google-chrome-os-x/) and [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=62435#c114) that added the feature. If true, this does not mean universal native support for Chrome.

Comment: Probably, it is not. Safari already support emojis, so for sure OSX does, and this is what it is being implemented in here. I will add that to my answer, apologies.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved by adding** [Emojis - Emoji Keyboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/emojis-emoji-keyboard/gaoflciahikhligngeccdecgfjngejlh) **extension to Chrome.**

Additionally, I checked that the [Chromoji - Emojis for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromoji-emojis-for-googl/negakbijaemdgbhklopmghphgaeadmpo?hl=en-US) extension also works.

**1st Note:** Emojis appear everywhere on the page except for inputs and textarea.

**2nd Note:** Any of these extensions additionally give us the ability to search for emojis along with the possibility of copying them.

Answer (score 1):

You can view emoji with a Chrome extension called **[Chromoji](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromoji-emoji-for-google/cahedbegdkagmcjfolhdlechbkeaieki/)**.
It works on Mac OS X, Windows and Linux as well.

Comment: Chromoji appears to no longer be available.

Comment: Published extension was removed, but source code is up here: https://github.com/robjdavey/Chromoji

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem could be solved by updating Internet Explorer to version 11 under Windows 7 x64 (several computers affected, all solved).

In my case, it was because I formatted the pc with pure, no-servicepacked Windows 7 x64. After SP1 on Windows 7 and IE11 have installed, all browsers started to show the emojis correctely. I used for test [this](http://www.copypastecharacter.com/emojis) site.

If the page shows squares all around the page, the error is not solved. If the page shows several kinds of symbols, than the error is eliminated.

Please tell us if this workaround was effective.